# asp.net - dynamically created dropdown not calling the event handler method in post back

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a page to do a heirarchical search, it starts with a dropdownlist and based on the value selected in the dropdown it will query the database and show the childs in another dropdown list and this continues as long as it hits the leaf... so I've first dropdown added dynamically and it has the event handler on SelectedIndexChanged, when I change the selected value, it triggers the postback **but however not calling event handler method**.. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.. or is it a bug??

Using a session variable to keep track the created controls

```
private List<DynamicControlProperties> PersistedControls 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_persistedControls == null)
            {
                if (Session[PersistedControlsKey] == null)
                {
                    Session[PersistedControlsKey] = new List<DynamicControlProperties>();
                }

                _persistedControls = Session[PersistedControlsKey] as List<DynamicControlProperties>;
            }

            return _persistedControls;
        }
    }
```

And in Page Init, recreating the dynamically generated controls

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

        // regenerate the persisted controls
        foreach (var prop in PersistedControls)
        {
            CreateControl(prop);
        }

    }
```

In page load, created the very first dropdown

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           // create the control
            CreateControl(....)

           // bind the data to the dropdown
         }
   }
```

In create control method, just creating a label and a dropdown wrap it inside a  and adding it to place holder

```
private DropDownList CreateControl(DynamicControlProperties dynamiccntrlprop)
    {
        // create a new HTML row
        HtmlGenericControlWithParentID tr = new HtmlGenericControlWithParentID("tr");
        HtmlGenericControlWithParentID td1 = new HtmlGenericControlWithParentID("td");
        HtmlGenericControlWithParentID td2 = new HtmlGenericControlWithParentID("td");

        // make sure we set the id and parentid
        tr.ID = string.Format("tr{0}", dynamiccntrlprop.ID);            
        tr.ParentID = dynamiccntrlprop.ParentID;
        tr.EnableViewState = true;

        // create a new label for dropdown
        Label lbl = new Label() { ID = string.Format("lbl{0}", dynamiccntrlprop.DisplayName), Text = dynamiccntrlprop.DisplayName };

        // create a new dropdown list
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList()
        {
            ID = string.Format("ddl{0}", dynamiccntrlprop.DisplayName),

            // set the postback
            AutoPostBack = true,

            EnableViewState = true
        };

        // subscribe for the select index changed event
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);

        // add the controls to table row
        td1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        td2.Controls.Add(ddl);

        tr.Controls.Add(td1);
        tr.Controls.Add(td2);

        // add the control to place holder     
        this.filtersPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(tr);

        return ddl;

    }
```

Here is the index changed handler,

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Enabled the viewstate,autopostback blah blah blah... recreated the controls with same id in post back.. tried all the answers in google.. but NO luck.. It does trigger the postback when i changed the index but not calling the event handler method..

Any ideas, please???

Many Thanks,
K

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that The CreateControl method is called on each and every page postback. This needs to happen to ensure that the dynamic control's event handler is hooked up after the postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // you shouldn't wrap the call to CreateControl in this 'if' statement
    //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    //{
           // create the control
            CreateControl(....)

           // bind the data to the dropdown
    //}
}
```

once you do this, the selected index changed event will fire.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It is beacuse new value of the dropdownlist don't be loaded.
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {

```
    // regenerate the persisted controls
    foreach (var prop in PersistedControls)
    {
        CreateControl(prop);
    }

    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
}
```